# Функция с переменным количеством строк

Tags: c, функции

Есть вот такая функция, аргументы - количество строк, а после строки.

```
void up_strings(int count, unsigned char string[150], ... ){
        int i;
        unsigned char  * str;
        va_list other_strings;
        va_start (other_strings,string);
        for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
            str = va_arg( other_strings,unsigned char* );
            printf("%s",str);
        }
        va_end(other_strings);
    }

    unsigned char str[]="adag asd";
    up_strings(1 ,str);
```

на этой строке происходит краш программы

```
str = va_arg( other_strings,unsigned char* );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
up_strings(1 ,str);
```

Так вы же ведь ничего и не передаете реально!

```
str = va_arg( other_strings,unsigned char* );
```

Что вы вот тут получаете? Какую-то фигню, простите, мусор, завалявшийся в стеке, превращенный в указатель...

Фигня и происходит :)

И еще - ну зачем вам передавать именно `unsigned char string[150]`, а не `unsigned char * string`? И почему не просто `char*`? Впрочем, на ответ к основному вопросу это не влияет.

Словом, или вызывайте `up_strings(0,str);`, или цикл переписывайте как `for(i = 1; i < count; i++ )`. Или перепишите функцию (покажу ниже).

Кроме того, ваш `string` в функции не используется - кроме как для `va_start`. Все это наводит на мысль, что вы не очень понимаете все эти `va_`. Они - только для необязательных аргументов, ваш `string` через них недоступен.

Вот мой вариант вашей функции:

```
void up_strings(int count, ... )
{
    int i;
    char  * str;
    va_list other_strings;
    va_start (other_strings, count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
        str = va_arg( other_strings, char* );
        printf("%s",str);
    }
    va_end(other_strings);
}
```